# XMPP for Machine to Machine (M2M) communication

Tags: python, xmpp, publish-subscribe

I am working on location-based services project where I have several sensors that need to send asynchronous readings to a server, which will correlate the readings and generate a result. There will be some level of sensor to sensor communication as well, and I am interested in using XMPP as a transport due to its efficient messaging, real-time nature and NAT traversal.

I am hoping to find an example of (python, or any other langauge) XMPP machine to machine (M2M) services, hopefully using a PubSub model for asynchronous communication rather than a polling-based RPC. I have not been able to find any examples online or in XMPP books that I have seen, as they seem to be mostly focused on XMPP for human interaction such as chat, video, etc.

The general requirements that I have to work with are:

1. Multiple sensors sharing data with each other over XMPP

2. Asynchronous (PubSub) communication, subscribing to messages of interest

3. Hopefully written in Python, but any language would be a good starting point

4. Server correlates data from all the sensors and generates results, which can be made available to subscribers

5. Easy configuration / setup through discovery

Any ideas about where to look, or a good starting point would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

XMPP for M2M sounds like a nice idea.

About clients and servers, see http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/pubsub/

In pubsub server does basically all the hard work, and you have to implement very little intelligence to clients. But this depends on what you want to do with published information. I haven't tested any clients which actually do something with the published information.

Answer (score 2):

This fits the pubsub model of XMPP pretty well.

- All your machines would be both publishers and subscribers.
- Your processing server in this case would also be another subscriber that will do its data processing as it receives published items.

Any example you find dealing with pubsub is easily applicable.  In XMPP, whether the JID (Jabber ID) represents a user of a machine is irrelevant, and pubsub is not actually oriented toward human interaction, unlike say, Multi User Chat.

There are many XMPP servers that support pubsub.  I have used [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html) and [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) for a similar purpose myself.  The server is of less importance to you, since any off the shelf product that supports PubSub will do the job.  More importantly is a client library that has pubsub support.  I know Smack has this, but it is a Java library not python.

Comment: Robin, I am trying to do M2M with OpenFire and Smack, but I could only create a connection with JID and password, and in my case I dont want to generate password for each entities which is unnecessary, is there any other way where I could bypass authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know anything with all those requisites but you can use SleekXMPP to build your own. It is pure python and well documented XMPP library. XMPP has been used to do computer-to-computer communication which is quite nice because you can just test it from your own chat client. Look for example, http://www.python.org/about/success/projectpipe/

Good luck